# Why cant I get multi views to work in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code. The issue is it isnt showing either view. What am i doing wrong?

```
.state('app.accessmanager.user.reactivate', {

    url: '/reactivate',
    Views: {
        '': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/accessmanager/reactivate.html'},
        title: 'ReActivate User',
        icon: 'ti-layout-media-left-alt',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'ReActivate User'
        },
        'sideBar': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/partials/AMSidebar.html'}
        }
```

here is the markup.

```html
<div class="sidebar app-aside" id="sidebar" toggleable parent-active-class="app-slide-off" >
    <div perfect-scrollbar wheel-propagation="false" suppress-scroll-x="true" class="sidebar-container">
        <div ui-view="sideBar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="app-content" ng-class="{loading: loading}">
 <header data-ng-include=" 'assets/views/partials/top-navbar.html' " class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"></header>
 <div data-ng-include=" 'assets/views/partials/main-content.html' " class="main-content" ></div>
</div>
```

if I do the following, it will at least display the sidebar but not the main content.

```
.state('app.access', {
    url: '/access',
        views: {
            'sideBar': {
                templateUrl: 'assets/views/partials/AMSidebar.html'
            }
        },
    template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-up"></div>',
    title: 'ACCESS MANAGER',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'ACCESS MANAGER'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a lack of codepen, I can only suppose :

Try to replace :

```
Views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/accessmanager/reactivate.html'},
    title: 'ReActivate User',
    icon: 'ti-layout-media-left-alt',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'ReActivate User'

    },
    'sideBar': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/partials/AMSidebar.html'}
    }
```

with

```
views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/accessmanager/reactivate.html',
    title: 'ReActivate User',
    icon: 'ti-layout-media-left-alt',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'ReActivate User'
     } // ADDED AFTER EDIT
    },
    'sideBar': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/partials/AMSidebar.html'}
    }
}
```

I have slightly modified the JSON structure of views:

Comment: what was the typo because I got what you have and it still doesnt work.

Comment: got it. Thanks but still only shows the content section and not the sidebar.  I am starting to wonder if it has something to do with the include for the content section.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out!!!

```
.state('app.accessmanager.user.reactivate', {
    url: '/reactivate',
        views: {
            'sidebar@app': {templateUrl: 'assets/views/partials/AccessManagerNav.html'},
            '':  {templateUrl: "assets/views/accessmanager/reactivate.html",
            title: 'ReActivate User',
            icon: 'ti-layout-media-left-alt',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {label: 'ReActivate User'}
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice the @ after sidebar with the app which is the state.  Also if you are going to have other attributes you have to enclose them in the {} like I did in the second templateUrl.